# How to read iw wlan0 station output

Tags: linux, wifi

I am trying to obtain the wifi rssi results at a very high rate and using the following command:

```
while true
do
    date -Ins
    /sbin/iw dev wlp3s0 station dump | grep signal
done
```

***Question:*** I wanted to understand how to read the output.

Does signal simply display the strongest signal and the signal from two antennas ?

Does the second line simply give a running average? Please advise.

```
2019-04-08T12:09:23,618290169-07:00
    signal:     -49 [-49, -53] dBm
    signal avg: -48 [-48, -52] dBm
2019-04-08T12:09:23,619857247-07:00
    signal:     -49 [-49, -53] dBm
    signal avg: -48 [-48, -52] dBm
```

Comment: Please learn how to format code in your question! Reformnat your code and output using the code formatting, please.

Answer (score 0):

`iw dev wlp3s0 station dump` returns the statistics about the connected devices.

The question does not provide the full printout, but it looks like you are getting the signal quality for 2 separate connected devices, and nothing about antennas. There should be a line `Station <mac address>`, which should tell you which connected device the stats are for.

Answer (score -1):

Could someone please take a look at the question. I am essentially trying to understand if the signal parameters displayed correspond to the two antennas. I searched all existing documentation including the source code of the IW utility, there is nothing conclusive that I am able to see to confirm my observation.